# Major Axis & Minor Axis Calculation in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, contour

The **major-axis** is the longest line that can be drawn through the object by two **endpoints**.

**Endpoints** of that line are from border points. For example {(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)} are those points.

With an algorithmic approach, the major-axis endpoints {(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)} can be found by computing the pixel distance between every combination of border points (pixels) in the object boundary.

And then finding the pair that create a line, **within** the object, with **maximum** length. The major-axis length of an object is the pixel distance between the major-axis endpoints and is given by the relation:

Sample Major-axis Length = sqrt((x_1 - x_2)^2 + (y_1 - y_2)^2)

As major-axis, **minor-axis** is the longest line that can be drawn through the object by two **endpoints**, except that it is **perpendicular** to the major-axis.

ok. And then I have a Python code to calculate it, which follows and I wrote it myself, because there was no code on the Internet to calculate and draw these two axes. The problem is that this code works well for images up to dimensions (400 * 400), but for higher dimensions due to the operational size of O(n^2) in several nested for loops, it has problems specially when total number of contours grows.

I need your help to optimize and streamline the following code. Also, if I want to register this code in the CV2 library, I don't know how to follow up. Thank you in advance for your guidance.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


from math import isclose 

import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Input_Path = ""

Input_image = cv2.imread(Input_Path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
RGB_image = cv2.cvtColor(Input_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
Contour_image = RGB_image.copy()

Binary_Image = cv2.imread(Simple_Binarization(Input_Path), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
Binary_Array = np.array(Binary_Image, dtype = 'uint8')


Contour, Hierarchy = cv2.findContours(Input_image, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

cv2.drawContours(Contour_image, Contour, len(Hierarchy[0])-1, (255, 0, 170), 1)

for l in range(len(Hierarchy[0])):
    cv2.drawContours(Contour_image, Contour, l, (0, 255, 0), 1)


List = []
  for c in range(len(Hierarchy[0])):
    for p in Contour[c]:
        point_array = np.array(p[0], dtype = 'int')
        List.append(tuple(point_array))

Major_List = []
  for p1 in range(0, len(List)):
    for p2 in range(p1+1, len(List)):

      Line_Image = np.zeros((Input_image.shape), dtype = 'uint8')
      cv2.line(Line_Image, List[p1], List[p2], (1), thickness = 1, lineType = cv2.LINE_8)
      Stencil = cv2.bitwise_and(Line_Image, Binary_Array)

      if (Stencil == Line_Image).all():
        Distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(List[p1][0] - List[p2][0], 2) + math.pow(List[p1][1] - List[p2][1], 2))
        Major_List.append([List[p1], List[p2], Distance])


Major_Axis = max(Major_List, key = lambda sublist: sublist[2])
Major_Axis_Image = cv2.arrowedLine(RGB_image, Major_Axis[0], Major_Axis[1], (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2, tipLength = 0.015)
Major_Axis_Image = cv2.arrowedLine(RGB_image, Major_Axis[1], Major_Axis[0], (255, 0, 0), thickness = 2, tipLength = 0.015)


Minor_List = []
  if (Major_Axis[1][1] - Major_Axis[0][1]) == 0:

    for p1 in range(0, len(List)):
      for p2 in range(p1+1, len(List)):

        if (List[p1][0] - List[p2][0]) == 0:

          Minor_Line_Image = np.zeros((Input_image.shape), dtype = 'uint8')
          cv2.line(Minor_Line_Image, List[p1], List[p2], (1), thickness = 1, lineType = cv2.LINE_8)
          Minor_Stencil = cv2.bitwise_and(Minor_Line_Image, Binary_Array)

          if (Minor_Stencil == Minor_Line_Image).all():

            Minor_Distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(List[p1][0] - List[p2][0], 2) + math.pow(List[p1][1] - List[p2][1], 2))
            Minor_List.append([List[p1], List[p2], Minor_Distance])

  elif (Major_Axis[1][0] - Major_Axis[0][0]) == 0:

    for p1 in range(0, len(List)):
      for p2 in range(p1+1, len(List)):

        if (List[p1][1] - List[p2][1]) == 0:

          Minor_Line_Image = np.zeros((Input_image.shape), dtype = 'uint8')
          cv2.line(Minor_Line_Image, List[p1], List[p2], (1), thickness = 1, lineType = cv2.LINE_8)
          Minor_Stencil = cv2.bitwise_and(Minor_Line_Image, Binary_Array)

          if (Minor_Stencil == Minor_Line_Image).all():

            Minor_Distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(List[p1][0] - List[p2][0], 2) + math.pow(List[p1][1] - List[p2][1], 2))
            Minor_List.append([List[p1], List[p2], Minor_Distance])

  else:
    Minor_Axis_Slope = (-1) * (Major_Axis[1][1] - Major_Axis[0][1]) / (Major_Axis[1][0] - Major_Axis[0][0])
    #Minor_Axis_Slope = (-1) * math.pow(Major_Axis_Slope, -1)

    for p1 in range(0, len(List)):
      for p2 in range(p1+1, len(List)):

        if (List[p1][0] - List[p2][0]) != 0 and (List[p1][1] - List[p2][1]) != 0 and isclose(((List[p1][0] - List[p2][0]) / (List[p1][1] - List[p2][1])), Minor_Axis_Slope, abs_tol = 1e-2):

          Minor_Line_Image = np.zeros((Input_image.shape), dtype = 'uint8')
          cv2.line(Minor_Line_Image, List[p1], List[p2], (1), thickness = 1, lineType = cv2.LINE_8)
          Minor_Stencil = cv2.bitwise_and(Minor_Line_Image, Binary_Array)

          if (Minor_Stencil == Minor_Line_Image).all():

            Minor_Distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(List[p1][0] - List[p2][0], 2) + math.pow(List[p1][1] - List[p2][1], 2))
            Minor_List.append([List[p1], List[p2], Minor_Distance])


Minor_Axis = max(Minor_List, key = lambda sublist: sublist[2])
RGB_image_2 = RGB_image.copy()

Minor_Axis_Image = cv2.arrowedLine(RGB_image_2, Minor_Axis[0], Minor_Axis[1], (0, 0, 255), thickness = 2, tipLength = 0.015)
Minor_Axis_Image = cv2.arrowedLine(RGB_image_2, Minor_Axis[1], Minor_Axis[0], (0, 0, 255), thickness = 2, tipLength = 0.015)



plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)
matplotlib.rcParams['font.size'] = 8

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1), plt.imshow(Input_image)
plt.title('Input_image'), plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2), plt.imshow(Contour_image)
plt.title('Input_image_&_Border'), plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3), plt.imshow(Major_Axis_Image)
plt.title('Major_Axis_Image'), plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)
  
plt.subplot(2, 2, 4), plt.imshow(Minor_Axis_Image)
plt.title('Major&Minor_Axis'), plt.tick_params(axis = 'both', which = 'major', labelsize = 8)
plt.show()
```

[image: an abstract image example]
[image: major and minor axes of it]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is expensive mostly because of the way you test for the line to be within the object. There must be more efficient ways of doing that. For example, look for intersection points of the line with the polygons that describe the object, there should be none in between the two end points. The max distance between two points on the contour, without the constraint of it being inside the object, can be obtained in O(n), see https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408/ Alternatively, look into medial axis (aka skeleton), it’s properties might be useful too.